# Skip default paper size thermal printer chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

Receipt height too big on thermal printer EPSON TM-T20II

But if i try to save as pdf the height is correct.

The css I am using

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: 80mm 110mm; margin: 10mm;
    }*, *: before, *: after {
        box - sizing: border - box;
    }
}
```

If I try to save as PDF is OK
[image]

If I try to print NOT OK
[image]

It seems that the size of the paper is the culprit
[image]

I am using roll paper 80mm. But on the printer paper size only I have 80x297 mm or 80x3276 mm

I have tried also

```
@media print {
    html,body {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: @KJ Thank's for custom form sheets tip. I tried and it work (although the print preview is still big). But now another problem: It seem that custom forms don't allow dinamic height (fixed 110mm it work) But what about dinamic height? ... You know another trick about? (Sorry for my english)

Comment: @KJ I'm so dumb! I had already found in the printer utility program the option to cut before and after the top and bottom space, I did it, but since the preview showed the same thing, I didn't press it to print. So, it works dynamically. Thank you

Comment: If you want post this as answer. So if the printer utility have this option ... tis is the answer

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [@KJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802527/k-j) I have solved this problem with the printer utility program (see comments above)

[image]

I also took a look at the forum what @KJ mentioned:
https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/print-page-using-command-line-print-settings-fit-remove-top-page-spaces/3866

Unfortunately in windows 10 this option (`save paper`) I can't find it anywhere. But if the printer utility have these settings option then it work (at least the printer we are talking about EPSON TM-T20II)

Still, the preview looks bad (as in the photos I put above) but when printing the printer removes the white spaces (before and after the text)